# pigpio spi : use an other GPIO for chip select

Tags: python, spi, pigpio

I'm using the [Waveshare High-Precision AD/DA Board](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/High-Precision_AD/DA_Board), and they not use the default chip select pin of RPi (GPIO# 7, 8) for SPI.

Using the [pigpio python library](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html), I want to know how to change the chip select pin to an other GPIO pin.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set the selected chip select GPIO low before the SPI call and set it high afterwards.  This will slow down the transfer.  If it slows down too much you will need to find an alternative solution.

Comment: Yes performance loss was my fear  

I was hoping it would be a change in configuration. 

I can also set AD/DA Board chip select as input and directly wire the RPi default chip select to it.  

What do you think?

Comment: If performance is an issue then if the program is running on the Pi (rather than running the script on a remote PC) then I would initially try using the Python spidev module.  That will not have the pigpio Python socket overhead per SPI command.  This can only be general advice. If you have a specific problem perhaps ask a new question giving more detail about what you are trying to achieve.